# Camel: exception in message listener is not GETTING HANDLED back in camel route

Tags: apache, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a camel route with exception handling capability, and also a defaultmessagelistener where it consumes the message from amq endpoint form camel route.

when an exception is thrown in the messageListener onMessage(Message message) it is not routing back to camel where i handle exceptions

```
onException(Throwable.class)
            .process(customErrorHandler);
```

Expected: on throwing exception in messagelistener come back to route and porcess errorHandler
Actual: catching the exception

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
try {
//dosomething which throws an exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //send back to camel route how??????
onException(Throwable.class)
            .process(customErrorHandler);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please show the config for how your message listener is configured, and how it talks to the Camel route?

Comment: there is no connection with camel route, I registered the listener with the activemq endpoint

Comment: Error handlers can only be defined as part of a Camel route definition, not within non-Camel code such as this message listener.

Answer (score 0):

just don't catch the Exception in your onMessage() method...let it propagate back up.  if that onMessage is invoked by a Camel route...then it should hit your Camel route's onException() clauses, etc.